# JavaScript: is there a way to initialize elements in a live collection automatically?

Tags: javascript, initialization, live, htmlcollection

**Consider the following example**

```
// a sample constructor
var SampleConstructor = function(element,options);

// a full live collection
var domCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

// bulk init
for (var i = 0; i < domCollection.length; i++) {
  if ('some conditions required by component') {
    new SampleConstructor( domCollection[i], {});
  }
}
```

**Questions**

- Will the newly added elements into the DOM get initialized by the sample constructor?
- If not, is there a way to do it without jQuery and without looping through the collection on an interval basis?

**Note**

The needed solution is for IE8+

Comment: May have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: If you deal with DOM manipulations by yourself it's easy to track changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
function compare(arr,newarr,callback){
  var index=0;
  var newindex=0;
  while(newarr.length!=newindex){
   if ( arr[index] == newarr[newindex]) {
     index++; newindex++;
   } else {
     callback (newarr[newindex]);
     newindex++;
   }
  }
}
//onload
var store=[];
compare([],store=document.getElementsByClassName("*"),yourconstructor);
//regular
var temp=document.getElementsByClassName("*");
compare(store,temp,yourconstructor);
store=temp;
```

I think its the most efficient to check. The only solution I know is to do it regularly using setTimeout. Another way would be to detect all js dom changes, something like:

```
var add = Element.prototype.appendChild;
Element.prototype.appendChild=function(el){
 yourconstructor(el);
 add.call(this,el);
};
```

Note: *very hacky*

Comment: What about the `propertyChange` event? I'm reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536956(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: _Note  Changing the innerText or innerHTML of child elements will not cause the onpropertychange event to fire for the parent element._

Comment: I think the `propertyChange` event triggers when I appendChild, it changes the `document.all.length`, remember I am interested to find a way to check when new ITEMS are added to the DOM.

Comment: thats a point.Yo still need to find the added elem, using the upper code...

Comment: Yep, so I won't need the `Element.prototype.appendChild` hack, I will find another way.

Comment: Is it safe to do the hack? Considering this would only be applied to IE8 only? Haven't tried yet, but seems to be the only, perhaps the best option.

Comment: It should. But you must be careful. If yourconstructor has an error, no script on your site is able to add elems. That could cause problems

Comment: All right then, I will just create a `CustomEvent` and trigger there instead the constructor call. Then, the `for()` I used above for bulk init will get wrapped as a handler for this custom event, it's gonna be a good solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample to illustrate my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649052/javascript-is-there-a-way-to-initialize-elements-in-a-live-collection-automatic#comment70498872_41649052). However, as you can see it doesn't keep track of DOM changes, indeed, I prefer the opposite way which is widely used by modern JavaScript frameworks like Angular : observe a raw data structure and update the DOM accordingly.

```js
// Observable

Observable = function () {
  this.observers = [];
};

Observable.prototype.addObserver = function (observer) {
  this.observers.push(observer);
};

Observable.prototype.emit = function (evt, args) {
  var i, n = this.observers.length;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    this.observers[i].update(this, evt, args);
  }
};

// Collection

Collection = function () {
  this.items = [];
  Observable.call(this);
};

Collection.prototype = new Observable();

Collection.prototype.size = function () {
  return this.items.length;
};

Collection.prototype.add = function (item) {
  this.items.push(item);
  this.emit("added", [item]);
};

Collection.prototype.removeAt = function (i) {
  var items = this.items.splice(i, 1);
  this.emit("removed", [items[0], i]);
};

// program

var i, s = "h*e*l*l*o";
var collection = new Collection();
var words = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var wordA = words[0], wordB = words[1];

collection.addObserver({
  update: function (src, evt, args) {
    this[evt](args);
  },
  added: function (args) {
    wordA.appendChild(
      this.createSpan(args[0])
    );
    wordB.appendChild(
      this.createSpan(args[0])
    );
  },
  removed: function (args) {
    wordB.removeChild(
      wordB.childNodes[args[1]]
    );
  },
  createSpan: function (c) {
    var child;
    child = document.createElement("span");
    child.textContent = c;
    return child;
  }
});

for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  collection.add(s[i]);
}

for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  collection.removeAt(i);
}

function rdm (max) {
  return Math.floor(
    Math.random() * max
  );
}

function addRdmLetter () {
  collection.add(
    (rdm(26) + 10).toString(36)
  );
}

function removeRdmLetter () {
  var n = collection.size();
  if (n > 0) collection.removeAt(rdm(n));
}

function showLetters () {
  alert(collection.items.join(""));
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Courier;
}

span {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

#buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>wordA</p><div></div>
<p>wordB</p><div></div>
<div id="buttons">
  <button type="button" onclick="addRdmLetter()">Add letter</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="removeRdmLetter()">Remove letter</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="showLetters()">Show letters</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This approach is very interesting. I am interested in a way to make them all happy the users of AngularJS, whatever JS that manipulate the DOM on the fly, for my `bootstrap.native` library, perhaps you can help provide a light and fast method to do this update.

Comment: At this point I am looking at a small utility function to do `onpropertychange` | `DOMAttrModified` | `DOMNodeInserted`, 4-5 lines of code that do the job. Still I am open to any suggestion YOU might have, since I have no idea of AngularJS.

Comment: @thednp There is nothing in common with Angular here, except the famous data binding pattern (data changed -> update DOM) that you can reproduce in many ways. I just want to show you that it would be better if you could keep complete control over DOM manipulations, but you may not be able to do that depending on your situation. My contribution stops here though.